# Prove the limit using mathematical induction and L'Hospital's rule.

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, induction

Prove that for every $c>0$ and for every polynomial $p(x) \in \mathbb{R}[x]$ the limit $\lim\limits_{x \to \infty}{\frac{p(x)}{e^{cx}}}$ exists and is eqaual to $0$.

Use the L'Hospital's Rule and mathematical induction by the degree $k$ of the polynomial $p(x)$.

Comment: What happens if you follow the given hint?

Comment: Tried to start with the indcution for k=0 but then I get something like: $\lim\limits_{x\to \infty}{\frac{a_0}{e^{cx}}}$ Does it even equals 0?

Comment: @MonsieurMolly $e^x$ goes to $\infty$ when $x\to\infty$. (also, degree of a polynomial -- I've never seen the word "grade" for that (?))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We know that the statement is true for the polynomial of degree zero (just a constant $b_0$)
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{b_0}{e^{cx}}=b_0\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{1}{e^{cx}}=0\ .
$$
Now, assume the property is true for a polynomial of degree $k-1$,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}b_m x^m}{e^{cx}}=0\ .
$$
Then, for a polynomial of degree $k$ we have
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{k}b_m x^m}{e^{cx}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}b_m x^m+b_k x^k}{e^{cx}}=\lim_{x\to\infty}\left[\frac{\sum_{m=0}^{k-1}b_m x^m}{e^{cx}}+\frac{b_k x^k}{e^{cx}}\right]\ .
$$
The first summand goes to zero by the induction hypothesis. For the second summand, just apply L'Hospital $k$ times. Differentiating $x^k$ $k$-times reduces the numerator to a constant, while the denominator remains an exponential. So again the limit is zero.

Comment: You could just apply L'Hopital to the polynomial and obtain a polynomial of degree k-1. There you can apply the induction hypothesis.